# Version number generation using rake

Tags: rake

On previous projects I've used Nant but want to try out Rake on a new project. With Nant I used the [Version](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/version.html) task in nantcontrib that generates a Version number for you. Is there anything similar out there for doing this using Rake?

Comment: jeweler provides rake tasks for Major.Minor.Patch version changing. Supposed to be for managing Gems, but I've used it in other non-gem projects.

Comment: @Douglas - This should be an answer!

Answer (score 1):

[Jeweler](https://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) provides rake tasks for Major.Minor.Patch version changing. It is designed for managing Gems, but I've used it in other non-gem projects purely for the version management features.